# how to put a button on the middle-right of the page (bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I m trying to put a button on the middle right of the page but i couldnt do it how much i tried. Any tipps for me ? 
p.s:tabPage is the biggest div here )

```
 var scriptRow = $('<div class="row"/>').appendTo(tabPage);
         var scriptRowInnereDiv = $('<div class="col-xs-12"/>').appendTo(scriptRow);
         var scriptDiv = $('<div class="col-xs-10"/>').appendTo(scriptRowInnereDiv);
         var scriptPanel = sincapp.ui.createScriptPanel(value, tabPage, "text/x-rsrc");
         scriptPanel.appendTo(scriptDiv);
         var ButtonDiv= $('<div class="col-xs-2"/>').appendTo(scriptRowInnereDiv);
         $('<button style="margin-right:0">-></button>').appendTo(ButtonDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

set all wrapped divs to desired height
something like this

```
    html,body, .container, .c, .tabPage{
       height:100%;
    }
```

and add

```
    .x{
       float:right;
       top:50%;
     }
```

and in html

```
     var scriptRow = $('<div class="row-fluid c"></div>').appendTo(tabPage);
     var scriptRowInnereDiv = $('<div class="col-xs-12 c"/>').appendTo(scriptRow);
     var scriptDiv = $('<div class="col-xs-10"/>').appendTo(scriptRowInnereDiv);
     var ButtonDiv= $('<div class="col-xs-2 c"/>').appendTo(scriptRowInnereDiv);
     $('<button class="btn-group x">-></button>').appendTo(ButtonDiv);
```

Comment: In css set containers height 100% and  put button in main container.

Comment: if this is for image slider use bootstrap carousel

Comment: i m trying to have a kind of pop up dialog which pops up after i click the button..But it needs to have the same size and height like the main container..for hours still no luck :(

Comment: Check this. This might suit your requirements - http://jsfiddle.net/azazaz/60e4vxwx/3/